# Spring boot app :fails to bootRun

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, gradle, spring-boot, build.gradle

I am trying to create a simple Spring Boot application using Gradle in Mac. On gradle bootRun, I get the following error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.

Process 'command:
'/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Exception is:org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':bootRun'. at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43) at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203) at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185) at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66) at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50) at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25) at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110) at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37) at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37) at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23) at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43) at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32) at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37) at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30) at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154) at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22) at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90) at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52) at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151) at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32) at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99) at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93) at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90) at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62) at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93) at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82) at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94) at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28) at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35) at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43) at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28) at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78) at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:48) at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51) at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28) at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43) at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170) at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237) at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210) at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35) at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24) at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206) at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169) at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33) at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22) at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33) at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45) at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54) at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35) at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1 at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:367) at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultJavaExecAction.execute(DefaultJavaExecAction.java:31) at org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.exec(JavaExec.java:75) at org.springframework.boot.gradle.run.BootRunTask.exec(BootRunTask.java:62) at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75) at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:227) at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220) at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209) at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:585) at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:568) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61) ... 57 more

build.gradle looks like this:

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.3.0.M2'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
} 
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot' 

jar {
     baseName = 'labSecurity'
     version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}


dependencies {
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
// JPA
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
runtime("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
// JSP
compile("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:8.0.23")
compile("javax.servlet:jstl:1.2")
// Security
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
testCompile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:4.0.1.RELEASE")
// cucumber
testCompile("info.cukes:cucumber-spring:1.2.3")
testCompile("info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.3")
testCompile("info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.2.3")
testCompile("junit:junit:4.11")
}

eclipse {
classpath {
     containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
     containers  'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
}
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
gradleVersion = '2.3'
}


// CUCUMBER
configurations {
cucumberRuntime {
    extendsFrom testRuntime
}
}

task cucumber() {
dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
doLast {
    javaexec {
        main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
        classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
        args = ['--plugin', 'pretty', '--glue', 'labSecurity', 'src/test/resources']
    }
 }
 }
```

Comment: gradle -version  , it will tell you the JVM it has picked up.  And also make sure you have set environment variables properly.

Comment: @Lovababu my JVM version is: 1.8.0_66 and gradle version:2.10

Comment: Did you set environment variables, Java and gradle.?

Comment: @Lovababu yes they have been set

Comment: Is there any other error beside that?  That's a generic error for task execution failure.  Can you do bootRepackage with no issues?

Comment: Did you ever fix this? Having same problem.

Comment: same issue here, haven't fixed it yet, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55655245/process-command-library-java-javavirtualmachines-jdk1-8-0-201-jdk-contents-ho